# (400) Bad Request, can't get response (Custom minecraft launcher)

Tags: c#, http-post

I just can't seem to be able to post a JSON to the webpage https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate and get a response.
when I post the JSON it just says

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

I've gone through many different scripts by others and created my own by converting the Java code to C#. Anyway, here's the code that has worked the best so far.

```
string authserver = "https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate";
byte[] rawData = fs.GetBytes(**[JSON]**);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(authserver);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
//request.ContentLength = rawData.LongLength;
WebResponse connection = request.GetResponse();
connection.ContentType = "application/json";
connection.ContentLength = rawData.LongLength;
Stream stream = connection.GetResponseStream();
stream.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
stream.Flush();
byte[] rawVerification = new byte[10000];
int count = stream.Read(rawVerification, 0, 10000);
```

**Edit:**
is it possible to do this code with webclient?

**Edit:**
it had an invalid input, the json didn't have the correct data needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (authserver);
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "YourJSON";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
using(Stream s = request.GetRequestStream ()){
    s.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
using(var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ()){
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream)){
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    }
}
response.Close();
```

Essentially You shouldn't call getResponse() before you submit your data

Comment: can you update your code to what you have now?
Also do you know what server expect in the submit data?

Comment: sure, but i don't know what you mean by server expect, the protocol is ssl and only uses POST, anything else and it gives 405 method not allowed

Comment: Bad Request generally means you didn't send data or your data does not look right. Now you get 405 maybe they block CORS

Comment: I only get 405 if i don't use post but when i do it says 400

Comment: I would suggest you to start by monitor what is sent out when you are using official launcher. Then you have an idea what to do.

Comment: i do, the source code i used to make the script is almost the exact same to the technic launcher's script which works, plus i can't find the official launcher's code so this is the best alternative

Comment: Are you using my code or yours? What is it sending out?

Comment: both, it gives 400 for both. and now that i think about it, it might be the json i'm going to do some testing otherwise i hope someone or maybe you could solve it